# Minor nuisance: NSMatrix cell order tag. 1- for first item, 0- for second item

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have a radio button group in my Cocoa App's UI.

When i intercept clicking on either of them, i query the selCell tag. For some reason it's always "0" for the second item, and "1" for the first. Shouldn't it be the other way around as the first item is, well, first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Tag for the cells in Interface Builder if you want them to match your expectations.

Comment: aha. Since i hadn't done that and i got values in the tag anyway, I thought it was somehow automatic, order based. Perhaps someone else in my firm set these tags and 0, 1 were just the values that pre-existed there.